# phonegap back button requires 2 taps

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 2.9 on a Galaxy S3 Android 4.2.1 to develop an application.  In the application i have overridden the default back button behavior.  The back behavior is simply a call to :

```
window.history.back();
```

I have 4 html pages.  After navigating all the way to page4.html, I hit the back button and successfully navigate to page3.html.  On page3.html I must hit the back button twice in order to successfully navigate to page2.html. It seems to behave this way regardless of the navigation plot.  The first "back" works fine, all subsequent ones require a double tap of the back button.

Stangely, when I put an `alert("going back!")` just before the call to `window.history.back()`,it displays properly for every "back" tap in the navigation. What could be causing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with phone gap, however, after a quick search I found this [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) on the phone gap web site. Maybe the issue is you are not using the documented process for adding events to back buttons? From  you descriptions it sounds like there may be an issue with event propagation or bubbling.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure how you are calling window.history.back() but you could do something like this:

```
$("#backButton").bind("click", backClicked);

function backClicked(){
window.history.back();
 }
```

and I highly recommend incorporating the [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library to any project that you want responsive buttons.

Comment: I am referring to the hardware back button, not an html button.